# Read emails in Objective C (ex. pop3)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, email, pop3

Does anyone know of any free and working external libraries for reading emails in Objective C (iPhone app)? For instance, you pass along the email, authentication, pop3 server, and then it can grab your messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [MailCore](http://cocoaobjects.com/mailcore/) could solve your problem here. [Git Repo](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore) here. But when I am not sure it supports POP3.

If the above ones are not satisfying then try [Chilkat Email (POP3/SMTP) Objective-C Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-objc.asp)

Comment: MailCore seems to be missing a library. If you download the trunk, it is missing the "libetpan" dependency.